# How to hook into filters in another plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am new to Wordpress so this question might seem stupid . I am having a hard time understanding how custom filters actually work .

So my understanding is you use `add_filter('filter_tag' ,'callback')` to add a filter first and then use `apply_filter('filter_tag' , $var)` to change the value of the $var using the call back function . Thus a code like below will fail  to hook into the filter  :

```
function callback($var){
    return ($var.'append');
}


$var = 'testing';
echo $var;
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');
echo $var1;
```

Instead it needs to be :

```
add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
```

Now my question is if I am hooking into the custom filter of another plugin(say named A) how is the `add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');`in my plugin B going to be executed before the `apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);` in A ?

I tried testing it out creating two plugins named A and B ( after reading somewhere that plugins are executed in alphabetical order) .

So a.php is like below :

```
function callback($var){
    return ($var.'append');
}

add_filter('custom_filter' , 'callback');
```

and b.php is like below :

```
$var = 'testing';
echo $var;
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
echo $var1;
```

The filter seems to be working as I am getting the desired output of testingtestingappend . But , if I have the apply_filters() in a.php and add_filter() in b.php the filter doesnt seem to work as I see the output of testingtesting . I am assuming this is happening because the plugins are getting executed alphabetically. If this is case then what is a correct way to hook into exiting plugin's filter ? Changing the plugin name doesnt seem to be reasonable .

I am editing and adding a video of the problem I am facing :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GlGzxrBc0DTCR_fpHINiB_yqW7xVIC0L

Comment: Do you already have an actual plugin that you are referring to as "Plugin A"?  If you could name it, I could review their specific code, and make a specific recommendation.  Otherwise, any answer I provide might require a lot of comment exchange between us before we found the answer you need.

Comment: I created two test plugins in my local host named A and B and tried it . It's not an actual plugin .

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment before .  So , the problem is not to do with d alphabetical order of the plugin name (like i thought before) as I was able to use the filter hook of an actual plugin  from my plugin while intentionally naming my plugin z . However , my other problem still exists .  I created two test plugin b and c . b has the hook and c has add_filter() . The hook doesnt work but if I make it the other way that is c has the add_filter() and b the hook , the filter starts working . Makes sense ? Any idea what might cause this ? My plugin doesnt do anything just echo stuff like above

Comment: I have added the problem as a video in a link to the original question . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested the key to my problem is the result of apply_filters is unpredictable if you use them before 'init ' as it is not guaranteed the hook is registered yet .

```
    //This is the filter hook 
function filter_function(){
$var = 'testing';
echo $var;
$var1 = apply_filters('custom_filter', $var);
echo $var1;
}
add_action('init' ,'filter_function');
```